# Google DataStudio row dimension limit

Tags: looker-studio

Google's DataStudio seems to have a limit for "row dimensions" to 2 if you use the "pivot table".
Is there a way to increase that limit?
Also there is a limit of 10 "row dimensions" if you use the normal table instead of the pivot table.

Comment: anybody else have an answer? we also need to simply show a "google sheet" style set of data in datastudio with 400 dimensions (i.e., columns)

Answer (score -1):

First of all, irrespective of the number of rows, you should use a single return statement.
Pass entire data (any number of rows of data) into a single ARRAY. In my case data[] is an Array where I'm passing more than 2 rows into this single array and returning the statement.
dataObj1 is the JSON Object and set1 is the variable name of the dataSet inside the dataObj1
dataObj2 is the another JSON Object and set2 is the variable name of the dataSet inside the dataObj2

```
var data = []; //this is the single array I'm talking above

dataObj.set1.forEach(function(play) {
 var values = [];

  dataSchema.forEach(function(field) {
  switch (field.name) {

   case 'total_impressions':
    values.push(play.impr_sns);
    break;

    default:
    values.push('');
  }
});
data.push({
  values: values
});
 });

dataObj2.set2.forEach(function(play) {
 var values2 = [];

  dataSchema.forEach(function(field) {
  switch (field.name) {

   case 'total_impressions':
    values.push(play.impr_sns);
    break;

    default:
    values.push('');
  }
});
data.push({
  values: values2 /*this is second array name values2[]  but pass into data[] array 
                    itself*/
});
 });
return { /* finally return rows:data */
schema: dataSchema,
rows: data
};

}
```